# Hamiltonian & QubitMappingType cannot be imported from qiskit.chemistry.core

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I'm trying to implement the same Jupyter notebook in  [The Variational Quantum Eigensolver — Programming on Quantum Computers — Coding with Qiskit S2E4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-A6G0WVI9w);however,I found a problem:
**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 12>()
     10 from qiskit_nature.circuit.library import UCCSD
     11 from qiskit_nature.drivers.second_quantization.pyscfd import PySCFDriver
---> 12 from qiskit.chemistry.core import Hamiltonian,QubitMappingType
     13 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     14 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.chemistry'
```

I know that qiskit.chemistry has been deprecated but don't know what code can replace
"from qiskit.chemistry.core import Hamiltonian,QubitMappingType"
Thanks for help!

Comment: "`from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance` try this out

Comment: Hi Lima! Thank you for your question. I looked around in the Qiskit Nature documentation and I found the QubitMapper found in qiskit_nature.mappers.second_quantization which also has a way to get the hamiltonian it seems. Let me know if this answers your question, otherwise I'll keep digging.

Comment: Aqua Chemistry was somewhat refactored when it was moved to Nature. Suggest also looking at the tutorials including this for the ground state computation https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/tutorials/03_ground_state_solvers.html The sample in the readme does things a bit more explicitly if you want to see the operators etc https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature#creating-your-first-chemistry-programming-experiment-in-qiskit

Comment: Thank for yours reponses! It seems that QubitMapper found in qiskit_nature.mappers.second_quantization is the right answer, but I don't know how to replace the "set up experiment" part with QubitConverter and ParityMapper

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the readme sample, link as I posted above. This does a computation with H2, instead of LiH, but it can be converted to LiH if you wanted - the freeze core and orbital reduction is done differently nowadays which you might want too to keep the LiH operator size down. The other thing the sample is missing is just the simple for loop to alter the molecule distances, but you could add that and do a plot for H2.

Comment: I will give it a shot. I'm a fully VQE rookie, so thank you so much for patiently teaching me!